# Aptitude command on fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, yum, package-management, aptitude

linux newbie here.  I'm running Fedora 12 and I have a script for Ubuntu installing a bunch of packages using aptitude.  I tried installing the packages using yum, but most of them aren't available.

The packages aren't very new or complicated stuff, is there any way get packages through aptitude on fedora? Or am I just going to have to find the Fedora equivalent of each package manually, for example the first package installed is g++ and of course this has a fedora equivalent.

Comment: While it _may_ be possible to run aptitude on Fedora, it is almost certainly a bad idea to install packages from repositories that are not specifically designed to work with Fedora.  Loading packages from an Ubuntu repository, for example, could severely mess up your Fedora installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll just have to manually find the equivalent packages.

For example, g++ on Fedora is gcc-c++. libfoo-dev is generally libfoo-devel or foo-devel.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing; it wasn't as difficult as I thought it would be looking for those differences in syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Install YumEx , I think it goes for Yum Extended, it's a graphical interface like synaptic, it will help you.

Comment: With the upgrade from Fedora 23 Workstation to 24, my old install command didn't seem to work anymore.  The package name could have been changed.  Here is my current command that should work: `sudo dnf install yumex-dnf -y;`.

Answer (score 0):

Aptitude is just a front end for APT. You can install both APT and Aptitude on your Fedora machine.

Apt can be installed through Yum (yum install apt), and Aptitude can be installed via apt-get.

Edit: [Direct Link to Aptitude](http://packages.debian.org/testing/admin/aptitude)

Comment: After apt-get update, apt-get can't find the aptitude package...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put your repo links in /etc/apt/sources.list